# how to make a post call to a web api controller from a mobile app

Tags: ajax, angularjs, cordova, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I have been trying to find out how to search for help, I am sure there is plenty of information out there but I do not know what to search for. I am using the apache-cordova plugin for Visual Studio 2013. I am creating a app with AngularJS. I need to make Ajax calls to my MVC 5 project. I can make a GET call without using Authentication, but I cannot allow anonymous POST calls. Would I include custom headers in my Ajax? This is my first mobile app so I am not sure how this works. 
Here is how I am making my GET call

```
app.factory('ItemGet', function ($http, $q) {
return {
    query: function () {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http({ method: 'get', url: 'http://example.com/api/apiItem' })
                .success(function (data) {
                    deferred.resolve(data);
                }).error(function (error) {
                    deferred.reject(error);
                });
        return deferred.promise;
    }
  }
 });
```

Update

```
  //Post New Job


   $scope.submitJob = function () {
    var data = {
         username: $scope.loginForm.username,
         password: $scope.loginForm.password,
         JobId: $scope.JobId,
         JobNumber: $scope.currentItem.JobNumber,
         JobName: $scope.currentItem.JobName,

      }
     var json = JSON.stringify(data);
   $http.post('http://example.com/api/apiJob/PostNewJob', json, {headers: {'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}})
    .success(function(data, status) {
        // success code
    })
    .error(function(data, status) {
        // error code
    });
};
```

Error
     `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4400' is therefore not allowed access.`

I have enabled Cors on the server side

```
 public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.EnableCors();
```

I did some searching but I am not sure what exactly to do.

I found a temp solution, I think?

```
 <system.webServer>
 <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
     <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://localhost:4400" />
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
```

How ever my console is showing the login page from my server. What does this mean?

```
<h2>Log in.</h2>
 <div class="row">
<div class="col-md-8">
    <section id="loginForm">
  <form action="/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2Fapi%2FapiJob" class="form-horizontal" method="post" role="form"><input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="akPAxvS8E2QJHtxFuSnHnFzdSE1Rs1HQExTcNIofMwCKIEZ6NZowUfO2SJZhAAPhxbK178KDOug9g0Y0Sn6_obTvM9cHj77b70btqRfHgwg1" />                <h4>Use a local account to log in.</h4>
            <hr />
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="Email">Email</label>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-email="The Email field is not a valid e-mail address." data-val-required="The Email field is required." id="Email" name="Email" type="text" value="" />
                    <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Email" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="Password">Password</label>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Password field is required." id="Password" name="Password" type="password" />
                    <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Password" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Remember me? field is required." id="RememberMe" name="RememberMe" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="RememberMe" type="hidden" value="false" />
                        <label for="RememberMe">Remember me?</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Log in" class="btn btn-default" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <p>
                <a href="/Account/Register">Register as a new user</a>
            </p>
      </form>        </section>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not exactly clear as to what your question is, I just assumed you are asking how to make ajax post with headers. The following is the syntax:

```
       // username and password is the payload your server accepts as poat data
       //$scope.loginform.username and $scope.loginform.password is your model name of your fields in angular
      //Iam converting it to payload format that will be accepted by the server
       var data = {username: $scope.loginForm.username, password: $scope.loginForm.password};
        var json = JSON.stringify(data);
     // json is the json data you need to post

        $http.post('http://example.com/api/apiItem', json, {headers: {'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}})
                .success(function(data, status) {
                  // success code
                })
                .error(function(data, status) {
                  // error code
                    });
                });
```

The following is the structure of json data Iam posting to the server. This structure might change depending on the payload your server accepts

```
        {"username":"john", "password":"max"}
```

Comment: But how do i log in to make that post. The post action in my web api controller has a authorize attribute on it. So some where in the ajax call i need to send my username and password

Comment: Please find my updated answer. Is this what you wanted to know?

Comment: It looks like it. Will check it out in the morning. Thank you

Comment: sure, let me know if you need any more details

Comment: sorry for the late response, I got your code plugged in but I am having trouble with the cross domain issue? Do I change the headers to solve this?